# How to install SIP on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to install SIP on Ubuntu 18.04. I got some information at [Installation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html). It says to use `python configure.py`, but when I am trying this command from the directory where I have downloaded and extracted SIP, I am getting the following message:

```
python: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi

Comment: "No such file or directory"... Did you confirm that the file exists?

Comment: file does not exist:$ ls configure.py
ls: cannot access 'configure.py': No such file or directory

Comment: "where you downloaded and extracted.." implies a manual download and not using PIP as documented on their website.

Answer (score 1):

You are somehow mistaken. I downloaded the same package as you, and it **does** contain `configure.py`.

Commands to get, unpack and configure:

```
cd /tmp/
wget "https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/sip-4.19.14.tar.gz"
tar -zxf sip-4.19.14.tar.gz
cd sip-4.19.14/
python configure.py
make
```

Those commands, if executed in order, provided you have build-dependencies installed, will work.

Comment: $ wget "https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/sip-4.19.14.tar.gz"
--2019-03-03 23:16:41--  https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/si. 66.151.32.244
.. connected.
Length: 1049688 (1.0M) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘sip-4.19.14.tar.gz’    
$ tar -zxf sip-4.19.14.tar.gz
$ python configure.py
python: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$ ls configure.py
ls:': No such file or directory
$ 
Hi vidario is the above dependency problem? Zulfi.

Comment: Yes, I was stupid and forgot a command :( you need to `cd`to the directory in question after unpacking :)

Comment: Hi configure.py worked but I got make file error: make[1]: Leaving directory
siplib.c:20:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'siplib.o' failed
make[1]: *** [siplib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/sip-4.19.14/siplib'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
:/tmp/sip-4.19.14$

Comment: You don't have all the build dependencies for the package.

Comment: Hi, I am this github link:https://github.com/honeynet/apkinspector  It says to install Qt which I did. What other dependencies I have to install kindly guide me. I have installed python. Zulfi.

Comment: I found that I have to install libpython-dev. I tried following but they are not working$ apt-get libpython-dev
E: Invalid operation libpython-dev
:/sip-4.19.14$ pip3 install libpython-dev
Collecting libpython-dev
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpython-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libpython-dev
/sip-4.19.14$ 
Somebody please guide me. Zulfii.

Comment: @vidarlo Shouldn't you include `make install` after make, as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/666336/156518)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

> SIP Download
>
> SIP is provided as a source distribution (sdist) and binary wheels
> from PyPI. To install it, run the following command:
>
> pip install sip

https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download